Inconsistent results from ApplyCentralImpulse with RigidBody2D
I'm working on a 2D top-down game using RigidBody2D for the player and enemies. They're bouncing and moving (using ApplyCentralForce) and detecting collisions just fine, however now I want to add a small kick-back to both parties when an enemy hits the player.
Current code in player script:
public void OnBodyEntered(Node other)
{
    Enemy enemy = other as Enemy;
    if (enemy != null && !invulnerable)
    {
        TakeDamage(1);
        Vector2 repelForce = (enemy.Position - Position).Normalized() * 10000;
        ApplyCentralImpulse(-repelForce);
        enemy.ApplyCentralImpulse(repelForce);

        invulTimer = hitInvulTime;
        invulnerable = true;
    }
}

Everything here seems to be working, collisions are detected, the invulnerability timer works, etc. About half the time the kickback also works as expected, pushing the player and enemy a bit away from each other. The other half of the time though, the player gets kicked 10-100x further back than expected, for no apparent reason.
Does anyone know what might be causing this? Happy to provide additional info as needed.

Do player's and enemies' RigidBody3Ds respond to physics collisions with each other before you apply the impulse? In this case, you may be adding up on the "default" response, increasing the final velocity even more.
